# How to share photos to Facebook from Windows 8 Picture Library?

Tags: windows-8

Maybe this is trivial and I just can't see it, but when I open Picture Library and try the Share charm to share or upload photos it only brings up the Mail and SkyDrive. No Facebook or People option.
However if I open the SkyDrive and try to share a photo the People option shows up.

My Facebook account is already linked and has all the permissions:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for this by installing the Share Photo application available at the store.

Comment: I'm aware of this app thanks, but I was looking into this to see it wasn't only me.